# Custom select in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, select

I have a problem with custom select in Internet Explorer. When I click to select, then the option area appearance is very bad. In chrome or firefox it works well.

Here is my example https://jsfiddle.net/kxytwo0e/1/. If you open it with IE and you select the last option, then you click again to the select then you will see the problem.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="custom-select">
    <select>
        <option>Here is the first option</option>
        <option>The second option</option>
        <option>The 3 option</option>
        <option>The 4 option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And here is my css code:

```
    /*custom-select start*/

.custom-select {             
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; 
    height: 36px; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 1;
    /*margin-left: 2px;*/         
}
    
.custom-select:hover { border-color: #999; }
.custom-select:before {
    background: url("../img/arrow-down.jpg") no-repeat right center;
    // color: #333;
    content: ""; 
    height: 100%; 
    padding:  0 0  0 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    right: 20px; 
    z-index: -1;
}
    
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .custom-select:before {
        height: 34px;
        right: 0px;
    }
} 
    
.custom-select select {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    /*color: #555;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
} 
    
.custom-select select::-ms-expand { display: none;}
.custom-select select:focus { outline: none; }
.custom-select select option{
    padding: 2px;
}
    
:-moz-any(.custom-select):before {
    background-color: #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1; 
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
 }
/*custom-select end*/
```

Thank you.

Edit: I realized the downvote was valid, because I did not specify what I expect and what I get instead. In Chrome and FireFox, the option area is shown just below the select, but in IE the option area is shown over the select. I would like to show the option are just below the select. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried to assign a margin-top for the first option? .custom-select > select > option:first would be the selector. You could apply this for IE either with css or javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution:

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/fnagel/GXtpC/light/

This works in Chrome, firefox and IE too.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<select name="speedC" id="speedC">
        <option value="Slower" class="whoo">Slower</option>
        <option value="Slow">Slow</option>
        <option value="Medium" selected="selected">Medium</option>
        <option value="Fast">Fast</option>
        <option value="Faster">Faster</option>
    </select>`
```

And you have to put the css and js code too.

And don't forget to add these to your project:

jquery.ui.core.css

jquery.ui.theme.css

jquery.ui.selectmenu.css

jquery.ui.core.js

jquery.ui.widget.js

jquery.ui.position.js

jquery.ui.selectmenu.js